# How to improve PPTP speed?

Tags: linux, vpn, performance, pptp

I want to supply PPTP(vpn) service to users, and I plan to supply one server for 30 users and give at

lease 10M bandwidth per user.  Of course， my server has enough bandwidth. I want to ask is my plan

possible and how to improve performance of PPTP server as far as possible？thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PPTP creates a tunnel and encapsulates PPP packets. So, communication speed can be improved by enabling PPP compression on both sides. However, this is primarily useful when you have:

1- A powerful server that can handle the compression overhead

2- Low-speed links on the users side that can benefit from the compression.

Another possibility is to optimize the protocol parameters/timers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you say "my server has enough bandwidth", but you also say 30 users at 10M per user.  I'll assume you mean simultaneous users and 10Mb/s (megabits per second, as opposed to MB/s, megabytes per second).

That's **300 megabits per second** you require.  Can you confirm that your PPTP server is on an internet pipe of gigabit speed?

Comment: Atually , my PPTP servers is on an internet pipe of gigabit speed!

Comment: Sorry, I say 30 users at "at least" 10M per user